# Searching for multiple objects in list not throwing proper output

Tags: python-2.7

Have created a list with two values as below

```
(Pdb) lis = ['ab', 'bc']
```

Searching for one value, gives a proper response

```
(Pdb) 'ab' in lis
True
```

Searching for both values gives response

```
(Pdb) 'ab' and 'bc' in lis
True
```

Now one value is changed and not getting proper response

```
(Pdb) 'bb' and 'bc' in lis
True
```

Is this the proper way of searching for multiple objects in a list.

Comment: `'ab' in lis and 'bc' in lis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct. Let's check what `'ab' and 'bc' in lis` is doing.

```
> 'ab' and 'bc'
'bc'
> 'ab' and 'bc' in lis
True
> 'zz' and 'bc' in lis
True
```

The correct way to do this is doing both conditions:

```
> 'ab' in lis and 'bc' in lis
True
```

Other way is doing sets (I love sets :P):

```
> not {'ab', 'bc'} - set(lis)
True
> not {'ab', 'zz'} - set(lis)
False
```

This is useful when you want to check multiple elements and it is easy to add even more in the future.